# Finding min value for substracting each element of two vectors

Tags: r, function

I have two vectors and I want to find which value of vector b minimizes the sum (a-b) for each element of a. The output I want is a vector of length a containing values of vector b.

```
a <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 25, 80)
b <- c(2, 9, 8.4, 7, 66, 32, 19, 4)
```

I have tried -

```
closest_longitude <- function (x, y) {
which.min(x - y)
}

closest_value <- sapply(a, closest_longitude, b)
```

but the results are gobbledygook.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you meant `sum(a-b)` or just `a-b`

Comment: just a-b, so the output should be a vector the same length as a, containing values of b

Comment: Perhaps `which.min(abs(x-y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have to consider the `abs` here in the function `closest_longitude`

```
closest_longitude <- function (x, y) {
      which.min(abs(x - y))
}

sapply(a, closest_longitude, b)
#[1] 1 1 8 4 2 2 7 7 5
```

---

If we don't use the `abs`, it will always be `5`

```
sapply(a, closest_longitude, b)
#[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

because the 5th element in 'b' is 66 and it will give the lowest negative value while subtracting with each element of 'a' and resulting in selection of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is "brute force" algorithm

```
 # 1. Vectors
 a <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 25, 80)
 b <- c(2, 9, 8.4, 7, 66, 32, 19, 4)
 # 2. Init settings
 sum_a_i_b_i_min <- Inf
 a_i_min <- 0
 b_i_min <- 0

# 3. Calculations
for(a_i in a){
  for(b_i in b){
    if(sum(a_i - b_i) < sum_a_i_b_i_min){
      sum_a_i_b_i_min <- sum(a_i - b_i)
      a_i_min <- a_i
      b_i_min <- b_i
     }
     print(paste0(a_i, " : ", b_i, " : ", sum(a_i - b_i)))
  }
}
# 4. Result
print(paste0("a_i_min = ", a_i_min, " / b_i_min = ", b_i_min, 
      " / sum(a_i_min - b_i_min) = ", sum_a_i_b_i_min))
```